# What functional method would help me to implement a speedback algorithm?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, combinatorics

[Speedback is the merging of speed-dating with feedback: a 2 min. 1-on-1 talk with all members of a group of people.](https://medium.com/@joshdesign/speedback-de-stigmatise-feedback-with-speed-dating-principles-4708d493fb63)

[I've made a similar question in Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/126073/organizing-a-speedback/126086#126086) to get some clues about the algorithm, but it's hard to convert it to functional programming.

Consider the input:

```
val team = setOf("alexandre", "sergiu", "joana", "tiago", "susana", "david")
```

I'd like to do like a round robin where all team members have to give feedback to eachother.
I want to group people in a way that maximizes the amount of simultaneous pairs so we reduce the total number of the rounds.

**The desired output would be:**

```
1st round:
"alexandre" to "sergiu"
"joana" to "tiago"
"susana" to "david"

2nd round:
"alexandre" to "david"
"sergiu" to "tiago"
"susana" to "joana"

3rd round:
...
```

until everyone "dates" everyone.

I have this:

```
fun main() {
    val team = setOf("alexandre", "sergiu", "joana", "tiago", "susana", "david")

    println(team.combinations(2))
}
```

[the output so far is the 15 possible pairs (combinations).](https://github.com/MarcinMoskala/KotlinDiscreteMathToolkit) Then I'm not sure which functional method to use to get the output above. I took a look at `groupBy`, `associateBy`, `partition` but none seem appropriate - or I'm too newbie in FP.

Comment: If you are looking for a solution based on a standard idiom you can use the array/list monad, which calculates the cartesian product. You only need a subset of it, so applicative isn't enough but you need the monad instance. However, if you want a more efficient solution you should implement a recursive solution of the algorithm described in the computer science answer.

Comment: I'm ok with the monad approach. do you have any example I can check?

Comment: I don't know Kotlin but AFAIK it is a multi paradigm language. So it probably comes along with the same shortcomings as Javascript. Here is an [JS implementation](https://repl.it/repls/ReflectingRoughAbstracttype) with a mutable `Set`. If you are looking for a purely functional approach you would have to replace the set with an immutable one based on a persistent data structure.

Comment: Ah sorry, I haven't met your round robin constraint. But maybe the example points you in the right direction.

Comment: that's a great starting point! thanks

Comment: joana is matching twice in round 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just turned the [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/126086/121560) you got on Computer Science Stack Exchange into Kotlin.

```
fun <T> roundRobin(list: List<T>): List<List<Pair<T, T>>> {
    val n = list.size
    return (if (n % 2.0 == 0.0) roundRobinEven(n) else roundRobinOdd(n)).map { 
        round -> round.map {
            (first, second) -> Pair(list[first], list[second])
        }
    }
}

//For each round (i), (i, n-1) and then Pair((j+i)%(n-1), (n-1−j+i)%(n-1) for the rest
fun roundRobinEven(n: Int): List<List<Pair<Int, Int>>> = 
    List(n-1) { i -> (1..(n/2-1)).map{ j -> Pair((j+i)%(n-1), (n-1-j+i)%(n-1)) }.plusElement(Pair(i, n-1)) }
    
//For each round (i), Pair((j+i)%(n), (n−j+i)%(n)) where 1<=j<=(n-1)/2
fun roundRobinOdd(n: Int): List<List<Pair<Int, Int>>> =
    List(n) { i -> (1..(n-1)/2).map { j -> Pair((j+i)%n, (n-j+i)%n) } }
```

And you can use it like this. Each list inside represents a round

```
val team = listOf("alexandre", "sergiu", "joana", "tiago", "susana", "david")
val rounds = roundRobin(team2)
for (round in rounds) {
    println(round)
}
```

Output:

```
[(sergiu, susana), (joana, tiago), (alexandre, david)]
[(joana, alexandre), (tiago, susana), (sergiu, david)]
[(tiago, sergiu), (susana, alexandre), (joana, david)]
[(susana, joana), (alexandre, sergiu), (tiago, david)]
[(alexandre, tiago), (sergiu, joana), (susana, david)]
```

[Link to Kotlin playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: it looks like joanna is matching with herself last line of output

Comment: @richytong You're right, I messed up by doing `(j+i)%(n-2)` instead of `(j+i)%(n-1)`. Thanks.

Comment: it makes a ton of sense now, I see how this can be done in n - 1 rounds

Answer (score 2):

Here's an **algorithm** written with my functional programming library. It is not ideal roundwise (takes 7 rounds for 6 people), but it gets you 15 combinations. It is not impossible to do exactly 5 rounds, please see the accepted answer. First the results

```
people [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' ]
round 0 [ [ 'A', 'B' ], [ 'C', 'D' ], [ 'E', 'F' ] ]
round 1 [ [ 'A', 'C' ], [ 'B', 'D' ] ]
round 2 [ [ 'A', 'D' ], [ 'B', 'C' ] ]
round 3 [ [ 'A', 'E' ], [ 'B', 'F' ] ]
round 4 [ [ 'A', 'F' ], [ 'B', 'E' ] ]
round 5 [ [ 'C', 'E' ], [ 'D', 'F' ] ]
round 6 [ [ 'C', 'F' ], [ 'D', 'E' ] ]
```

Here's the implementation

```js
const {
  pipe, fork, tap, switchCase,
  map, filter, transform,
  and, not, eq, get,
} = require('rubico')

const identity = x => x

// [person] => Map { person => (Set { person }) }
const makeTracker = transform(
  map(fork([
    person => person,
    () => new Set(),
  ])),
  new Map(),
)

const db = new Map()

const saveTracker = async tracker => { db.set('tracker', tracker) }

const hasTracker = async () => db.has('tracker')

const getTracker = async tracker => db.get('tracker')

const isNotIn = set => x => !set.has(x)

// { people, tracker } => { people, tracker, pairs }
const algorithm = ({ people, tracker }) => {
  const matchedThisRound = new Set()
  return fork({
    people: identity,
    tracker: () => tracker,
    pairs: transform(
      pipe([
        filter(isNotIn(matchedThisRound)),
        map(person => {
          for (const other of people) {
            // console.log('person:other', `${person}:${other}`)
            if (other === person) continue
            if (tracker.get(person).has(other)) continue
            if (matchedThisRound.has(other)) continue
            tracker.get(person).add(other)
            tracker.get(other).add(person)
            matchedThisRound.add(person)
            matchedThisRound.add(other)
            return [person, other]
          }
        }),
        filter(Array.isArray),
      ]),
      [],
    )
  })(people)
}

// [person, person, person, person, ...] => [[person, person], [person, person], ...]
const matchmake = pipe([
  fork({
    people: identity,
    tracker: switchCase([
      hasTracker, getTracker,
      makeTracker,
    ]),
  }),
  algorithm,
  tap(pipe([get('tracker'), saveTracker])),
])

const didEveryoneMatch = (tracker, people) => {
  for (const [, set] of tracker) {
    if (set.size < people.length - 1) return false // 1 for yourself
  }
  return true
}

const main = async () => {
  const people = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']
  console.log('people', people)
  let i = 0
  while (true) {
    const round = await matchmake(people)
    const { tracker, pairs } = round
    console.log('round', i, pairs)
    if (didEveryoneMatch(tracker, people)) break
    i += 1
  }
}

main()
```

some fun stats

- 100 people takes 127 rounds
- 53 people takes 63 rounds
- 1000 people takes 1023 rounds

You can play with the amount of people yourself if you drop this in for `people`

```js
const people = Array.from((function*() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 53; i++) yield `${i + 1}`
})())
```

Comment: This is cool, but I'm fairly sure you can have just n-1 rounds with an even number of people and n rounds otherwise. See this answer, it seems to work, at least for n = 6 and n=7 - https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/126086/121560

Comment: just thinking about it, I can tell my answer is off the mark. Thank you for clarifying.